# get output of execution perl

Tags: perl

Usually to get the output of a command I run from perl I use back tick

```
my $value = `pwd`;
```

How do I do it though if I need to insert a variable within the back ticks ``?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Text inside backticks is interpolated before it is passed to the operating system in the same way as text inside double quotes. So these statements all do what they look like they do:

```
$value = `$command`;
$value = `$someCommand $arg`;
$value = `$someOtherCommand @list`;
```

`qx()` is another way of running an external command and returning the output. If for some reason you *don't* want Perl to interpolate your command, you can run `qx` with the single-quote delimiter.

```
$value = qx'echo $PATH';   # shell's $PATH, not Perl's $PATH
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just insert it. E.g.

```
my $dir  = "/home"
my $text = `ls -l $dir`;

print $text;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
my $hello = "world";
my $value = ` echo $hello `;
print $value;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use qx() instead of backticks. Eg. my ($used, $dir); ($used) = qx(du -k $dir);

Comment: `qx` and backticks interpolate their arguments in the same way. Using `qx` instead of backticks is a matter of style, not of functionality.

Comment: no need to use qx instead of back ticks... both work (see mob's answer)